# Make A Material Appear Only When Light Strikes It

Tags: materials, lighting

Is there a way to make a material that only shows one material initially, but when light strikes it (a spotlight, for example) it would change material only where it strikes it?[image: Something like this (I made this in Photoshop)]

Something like this (I made this in Photoshop)

Comment: Can you dio this with a Principled Volume node somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Eevee with the `Shader to RGB` node, the value of which can tell you how much light has hit the material. The following node setup produces something similar to the picture you gave:
[image: setup]

result:
[image: result]

If you are trying to do this in Cycles, that is somewhat more difficult, as the shader to rgb node is only available in Eevee. If you want to switch between two fully separate materials instead of just two colors, you can plug the output of the shader to rgb into the factor of a mix shader.

Comment: It sort of works. One, I need it to work in cycles. Two, when I combine two textures made from images (i.e. Megascans textures or polligon textures) I get a pink texture.